# How to configure the linking g++ with opecv properly in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, g++, libraries

I'm new to opencv. And I'm found out that the `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs` should be used to make compile smoothly. But I just don't know why keeping get the "undefined reference" error when compiling, the output results and  my Makefile are as follows:

**1. For outputs:**

```
g++ -Wall -g opencv.cpp
/tmp/ccg5WiIh.o: In function `main':
/home/akatsuki/Documents/Projects/simpleTest/opencv/opencv.cpp:14: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
/home/akatsuki/Documents/Projects/simpleTest/opencv/opencv.cpp:25: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
/home/akatsuki/Documents/Projects/simpleTest/opencv/opencv.cpp:26: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/home/akatsuki/Documents/Projects/simpleTest/opencv/opencv.cpp:29: undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
/home/akatsuki/Documents/Projects/simpleTest/opencv/opencv.cpp:31: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/tmp/ccg5WiIh.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:622: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccg5WiIh.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:664: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccg5WiIh.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:592: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccg5WiIh.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:704: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccg5WiIh.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat&&)':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:1215: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'opencv.o' failed
make: *** [opencv.o] Error 1
```

**2. For Makefile:**

```
CC = g++
CCFLAG = -Wall -g
Linker = `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs

all: opencv.exe

opencv.exe: opencv.o
    g++ -o $@ opencv.o $(Linker)
    chmod a+x $@

opencv.o: opencv.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCFLAG) opencv.cpp
```

Could anyone help me figure out the problem? Thanks~

Comment: Looks like you're also using the HighGUI module, but didn't link that...

Comment: I made modified the linker to `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv -I/usr/include/opencv -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs`, however, the same errors still bothers me. My original code includes:  #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

Comment: Seems I found a solution: `g++ pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencv.cpp .cpp` opencv.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv``. I don't know what the magic ``basename opencv.cpp .cpp`` does here, but it works anyway :)

Comment: Thank you for your inspiration :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who searches relevant issues, I leave reply.

Following command prints directories of OpenCV header files.

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
// -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include
```

Following command prints shared object files
(under `/usr/local/lib` directory in following case)
which are used for dynamic linking.
Dynamic linking is to link your excutable file (like `main` file)
to shared object files (like `.so` files) at runtime

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
// -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudaobjdetect 
// -lopencv_cudastereo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_cudafeatures2d 
// -lopencv_superres -lopencv_cudacodec -lopencv_videostab 
// ...
```

You can use above printed dependencies
(header file directories and shared object files) in your compilation command
by writing `pkg-config --cflags opencv` and `pkg-config --libs opencv`

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` \
-o main \
/your_cpp_file_path/source.cpp \
`pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Note that `` ` `` is backtick character, not `'`
backtick character in linux command is used
to use a result from command in command

For example, this part `pkg-config --cflags opencv` is replaced
with the result from `pkg-config --cflags opencv`